# How to run a php include file at regular intervals to collect data

Tags: javascript, php

I have a webpage index.php page which gets a time value from time.php.

Now the javascript variable gets the time value on page load from time.php. Is there any way that I can refresh the include time.php (inside index.php) on regular intervals so that my javascript variable can get the updated value? So my goal was to show changes of the time without refreshing the whole page.I have tried the jquery load() function, but of no success :( Thank you so much for your time !!

Time.php ( connects to Oracle DB to get time val)

```
<?php 
error_reporting(0);
ini_set('display_errors', 0); //to display no errors
ob_start();
$conn=oci_connect('abcd', 'abcd', 'orcl');
$stid = oci_parse($conn, "***QUERY*******");
            $r=oci_execute($stid);
            while ($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_BOTH)) { 
              
                echo $row[0].(",");

                $time = ob_get_contents(); //has the time value
                 
                
            }
            
            ob_get_clean();
 ?>
```

index.php

````
<?php 
include 'time.php';
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>

<script>

var time= <?php echo json_encode($time); ?>; //value coming from time.php on page load

</script>
</body>
</html>

```
````

Answer (score 1):

Do you need the time to come from PHP?

Otherwise in JS you could simply use [setInterval()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp):

```js
var time = Date.now();
setInterval(function () {
  time = Date.now();
}, 1000);
```

---

If you have to get the time from PHP without reloading the page, then you'll need to use AJAX, for example, using [fetch()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API):

```js
fetch('/time.php')
  .then(
    function(response) {
      // do something with response
    }
  )
  .catch(function(err) {
    // do something with err
  });
```

---

Finally, you can use a mix of setInterval() and fetch() to call time.php at regular interval:

```js
setInterval(function () {
  fetch('/time.php')
    .then(
      function(response) {
        // do something with response
      }
    )
    .catch(function(err) {
      // do something with err
    });
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Hey its not normal time, its another time value which gets updated in the database every minute.

Comment: Updated my response

Comment: Hey Is it SetTimeout ? or Set Interval ? i see that you have used SetTimeout? Thankss!!

Comment: Thanks. but for some reason i can't get it to work :( . The values are not updating.

Comment: What errors are you getting? What is the response from `fetch()`?
I'd recommend your time.php to respond with JSON)

Comment: Grim's answer is correct. There are a number of issues that might case it to not work, however. I'd start by making sure that you can visit the endpoint by typing the URL in  the browser (e.g. `http://example.com/time.php`) and cause the `time.php` file to run (and verify this by looking at the output in the browser, or looking at server logs). Once you can do that, then you can make the same request via JavaScript (via `fetch`) and deal with any errors (e.g. CORS, authentication, configuring the request headers, etc.) as needed.

Comment: Yes i have done that.  when i run the file http://example.com/time.php  i get the output. And my javascript variable also gets the value on from time.php on pageload.